# How to determine if user account is enabled or disabled

Tags: c#, active-directory, attributes, directoryservices

I am throwing together a quick C# win forms app to help resolve a repetitive clerical job.

I have performed a search in AD for all user accounts and am adding them to a list view with check boxes.

I would like to default the listviewitems' default check state to depend upon the enabled/disabled state of the account.

```
string path = "LDAP://dc=example,dc=local";
DirectoryEntry directoryRoot = new DirectoryEntry(path);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryRoot,
    "(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person))");
SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult result in results)
{
    DirectoryEntry de = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(
        (string)de.Properties["SAMAccountName"][0]);
    // lvi.Checked = (bool) de.Properties["AccountEnabled"]
    lvwUsers.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

I'm struggling to find the right attribute to parse to get the state of the account from the DirectoryEntry object. I've searched for [AD User attributes](http://www.google.com/search?q=AD+User+attributes), but not found anything useful.

Can anyone offer any pointers?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

this code here should work...

```
private bool IsActive(DirectoryEntry de)
{
  if (de.NativeGuid == null) return false;

  int flags = (int)de.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;

  return !Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0002);
}
```

Comment: Damn, you're faster, but here is a link about what all the flags are meaning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680832.aspx

Comment: Maybe this link will complement Oliver's **[Flags](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144/en-us)**

Comment: If flags is zero then this will return true which is incorrect - just a note to handle this case.

Comment: the convert.toboolean is not very readable. better use return (flags & 2) = 0

Comment: I did return flags | 0x0002 == flags. If this returns true then the disabled flag is set.

Comment: I need to know when have certain accounts been disabled  And who disables the account.

Comment: what is the name of the `userAccountControl` attribute for OpenLDAP?

Comment: @Varsh `userAccountControl` is a property bound to a directory entry which normally belongs to `objectClass=user` => so you would use a filter on the DirectorySearcher like 
`(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=some_NAME))`

Answer (score 14):

Using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement:
domainName and username must be the string values of the domain and username.

```
using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
{
    using (var foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username)) 
    {
        if (foundUser.Enabled.HasValue) 
        {
            return (bool)foundUser.Enabled;
        }
        else
        {
            return true; //or false depending what result you want in the case of Enabled being NULL
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `((UserPrincipal)foundUser).Enabled == true` is what worked for me

Answer (score 12):

Not that anyone asked, but here's a java version (since I ended up here looking for one). Null checking is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
private Boolean isActive(SearchResult searchResult) {
    Attribute userAccountControlAttr = searchResult.getAttributes().get("UserAccountControl");
    Integer userAccountControlInt = new Integer((String) userAccoutControlAttr.get());
    Boolean disabled = BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject(userAccountControlInt & 0x0002);
    return !disabled;
}
```

Comment: Upvote for taking the time to share because the title isn't language specific and this might really help someone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
    ADUserAccountControl flags;
    Enum.TryParse(de.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value.ToString(), out flags);

    if(flags.HasFlag(ADUserAccountControl.ACCOUNTDISABLE)
    {
        // account is disabled
    }
```

Here is a complete list of all possible flags:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties
    /// </summary>
   [Flags]
   public enum ADUserAccountControl : long
   {            
        SCRIPT = 0x0001,
        ACCOUNTDISABLE = 0x0002,
        HOMEDIR_REQUIRED = 0x0008,
        LOCKOUT = 0x0010,
        PASSWD_NOTREQD = 0x0020,
        PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE = 0x0040,
        ENCRYPTED_TEXT_PWD_ALLOWED = 0x0080,
        TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT = 0x0100,
        NORMAL_ACCOUNT = 0x0200,
        INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT = 0x0800,
        WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT = 0x1000,
        SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT = 0x2000,
        DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD = 0x10000,
        MNS_LOGON_ACCOUNT = 0x20000,
        SMARTCARD_REQUIRED = 0x40000,
        TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION = 0x80000,
        NOT_DELEGATED = 0x100000,
        USE_DES_KEY_ONLY = 0x200000,
        DONT_REQ_PREAUTH = 0x400000,
        PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 0x800000,
        TRUSTED_TO_AUTH_FOR_DELEGATION = 0x1000000,
        PARTIAL_SECRETS_ACCOUNT = 0x04000000,
    }
```

Comment: Nivce.
I would recommend to decorate enum with FlagsAttribute:

[Flags]
public enum ADUserAccountControl

Comment: @You are right, thanks! Edit made

Answer (score -1):

I came here looking for an answer, but it was only for `DirectoryEntry`. So here is a code that works for `SearchResult` / `SearchResultCollection`, for people who had the same problem:

```
private bool checkIfActive(SearchResult sr)
{
    var vaPropertiy = sr.Properties["userAccountControl"];

    if (vaPropertiy.Count > 0) 
    {
        if (vaPropertiy[0].ToString() == "512" || vaPropertiy[0].ToString() == "66048") 
        {
            return true;
        } 
        
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Will not work for every case. There are a lot of more flags which can be set at the same time. You have to check the flag usind "HasFlag(..)"

Comment: As info, SearchResult have a GetDirectoryEntry() method.