# Directory Entry - Account Active

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to implement the IsActive method described here [Is Account Active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005637/how-to-determine-if-user-account-is-enabled-or-disabled), but i'm getting an object reference not set to an instance of the the object.

```
       private bool IsActive(DirectoryEntry de)
    {
        DirectoryEntry myEntry = GetDirectoryEntry();
        if (myEntry.NativeGuid == null) return false;

        int flags = (int)myEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;

        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0002)) return true; else return false;

        return false;
    }
   private void SubmitData()
    {
        System.Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        logInfo.IPaddress = IPAddress;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUser.Text))
        {
            string username = txtUser.Text.ToString();
            if (IsActive(de) != false)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(passwordLastSet).TotalHours > 1)
                {
                    lblPasswordLastSet.Text = passwordLastSet.ToString();
                    lblStatus.Text = "all is good";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "oops, you reset your password less than 24 hours ago!";
                    lblPasswordLastSet.Text = passwordLastSet.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "your account is not active";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find user by name
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity("John Doe");

if(user != null)
{
   // check if account is locked out
   if(user.IsAccountLockedOut)
   {
      // do something if locked out....
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD:

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to take the route you suggested