# Ldap user authentication not working for locked or disabled account

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ldap

I am working on a website to manage ldap. I am stuck in a situation, when I am trying to authenticate user with account locked or disabled it fails. 
What I want to do is first authenticate user after that show message that account locked or disabled.

I am coding like this

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(new       LdapDirectoryIdentifier("SJTPNOC.com", 636));
connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((con, cer) => true);
connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;        
connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;       
connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
connection.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);   
connection.Credential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
using (connection){
connection.Bind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks  but what kind of error?

Comment: like what u want to do is clear however, when ure running ur app with the above code is it giving any kind of error? i cant run ur code right now as im not on my desk

Comment: this link will be helpful to some extent .... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005637/how-to-determine-if-user-account-is-enabled-or-disabled

Comment: I didn't find anything helpfull.

Comment: @jbl Hi I need your help again.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand this- if the user is locked or disabled they won't be able to authenticate. You should either catch the error returned from LDAP and use that information to display a friendly message to the user, or do a lookup on the user and read the attribute that indicates the status of the user (e.g. userAccountControl in AD).

Comment: And each LDAP server reports the error for a locked user or bad password differently.

Comment: Ok I'll manage locked or disable account but its not working for user must change password at next logon also. Without authentication how I can allow user to change password.

Comment: @mayank.karki You need to use the change-password extended operation while authenticated as an admin user.