# Determine if a directory user's account is disabled account using PrincipalContext approach

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have been looking for a way to determine if a directory user's account is disabled or not but using the `PrincipalContext` approach:

```
using (var validatePrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext())
{          
    using (var retrievedUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(validatePrincipalContext, directoryUserName))
    {
        if (retrievedUserPrincipal == null)
        {
             LogMessage(String.Format("User {0} failed to verify on {1}.", directoryUserName, domainNameV), Severity.Error);

             throw new PlatformException(ErrorCode.DomainCredentialsFailed, new Dictionary<string, string>
             {
                {"ADUserName", directoryUserName},
                {"DirectoryIdentifier", domainNameV}
             });
        }

        // Actual validation
        if (validatePrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(directoryUserName, directoryUserPassword))
        {
            LogMessage(String.Format("User {0} verified successfully on {1}.", directoryUserName, domainNameV), Severity.Info);

            return retrievedUserPrincipal.UserPrincipalName;
        }

        LogMessage(String.Format("User {0} failed to verify on {1}.", directoryUserName, domainNameV), Severity.Info);

        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

I have searched here and see some people using the second approach with directories: The DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher approach ([How to determine if user account is enabled or disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005637/how-to-determine-if-user-account-is-enabled-or-disabled)). I cannot use that as I have done everything with the `PrincipalContext`

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple properties and methods on the `UserPrincipal` that you can check:

- `Enabled` : whether or not the user's account is enabled
- `IsAccountLockedOut()` : Returns a Boolean value that specifies whether the account is currently locked out.

Check out the [official MSDN documentation on `UserPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I'm amazed how I missed this one. I'll test it out.