# C# Issue with manipulating ActiveDirectory users

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm writing some kind of a mini AD tool (with VS-C#) to our organization and got into an issue.

I have a main function that searches the user (when I click on it in a listview) and some functions that manipulate the user's object.

```
public DirectoryEntry GetUser(string username)
    {
        try
        {
            Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
            GlobalCatalog gc = currentForest.FindGlobalCatalog();

            using (DirectorySearcher searcher = gc.GetDirectorySearcher())
            {
                searcher.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + username + "*))";
                SearchResult results = searcher.FindOne();
                if (!(results == null))
                {

                    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(results.Path, strAdminUser, strAdminPass, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
                    de.RefreshCache(new string[] { "canonicalName" });
                    de.Path = de.Properties["canonicalName"].Value.ToString();
                    de.CommitChanges();
                    return de;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and here's an example of a function that checks if the user is locked:

```
public bool IsUserLocked(string username)
    {
         try
         {
             DirectoryEntry de = GetUser(username);
             string attName = "msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed";
             de.RefreshCache(new string[] { attName });
             const int UF_LOCKOUT = 0x0010;
             int userFlags = /*(int)*/Convert.ToInt32(de.Properties[attName].Value);
             if ((userFlags & UF_LOCKOUT) == UF_LOCKOUT)
             {
                 return true;
             }
             de.Dispose();
             return false;
         }
         catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException e)
         {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            return false;
         }
      }
```

The function that checks the locked status of a user always fails with an error: **"Unspecified error"**, but if I'm not changing the Directory Entry's path in the first function I get **"The server is unwilling to process the request"** error (I'm using proper service username and password with all the permissions needed) but still it happens.

Can someone spot the issue?

Comment: do a google search.. there are several examples on the web as well as on Stackoverflow in regards to checking the locked status using C# check here for starters - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005637/how-to-determine-if-user-account-is-enabled-or-disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...

This has solved my issue:
**de.Path = results.Path.Replace("GC://DCNAME.", "LDAP://");**
Since I'm searcing on the Global Catalog, I had to replace a portion in the path to match it to the correct path:

```
public DirectoryEntry GetUser(string username)
    {
        try
        {
            Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
            GlobalCatalog gc = currentForest.FindGlobalCatalog();

            using (DirectorySearcher searcher = gc.GetDirectorySearcher())
            {
                searcher.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + username + "*))";
                SearchResult results = searcher.FindOne();
                if (!(results == null))
                {

                    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(results.Path, strAdminUser, strAdminPass, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
                    de = new DirectoryEntry(results.Path);
                    de.Path = results.Path.Replace("GC://DCNAME.", "LDAP://");
                    de.CommitChanges();
                    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(de.Path);
                    return de;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now the path returns to the function called **GetUser** in the correct format :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace? If you have no issue using the new namespace, there's a simpler way to check if user account is `locked` and `unlock` if needed.

```
public bool IsUserLocked (string username)
{
   using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com")
    {
       using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username)
       {
          if (user != null) return user.IsAccountLockedOut();
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And similarly, you can `unlock` the user account if needed.

```
...

if (user != null)
{
   user.UnlockAccount();
   user.Save();
}
```

Comment: We have a domain and subdomain in the organization so I first need to determine what is the user's domain then use your example....

Comment: Do you have the `username` prior to knowing the domain?

Comment: Yes, I get a list on a listview with users matching a search criteria.

I use this to get the list:

Comment: `code` public List<SearchResult> GetADUserDetails(string username)
        {
            List<SearchResult> resultList = new List<SearchResult>();
            Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
            GlobalCatalog gc = currentForest.FindGlobalCatalog();
            using (DirectorySearcher searcher = gc.GetDirectorySearcher())
            {
                searcher.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + username + "*))";

                SearchResultCollection allUsers = searcher.FindAll();

Comment: foreach (SearchResult result in allUsers)
                {
                    resultList.Add(result);
                }
                searcher.Dispose();
                gc.Dispose();
                currentForest.Dispose();
                return resultList;

            }
        }

Comment: You can grab the domain name for a logged in user this way `string domainName;
domainName = System.Environment.UserDomainName;` Is that something you're looking for?

Comment: Well my proggy is a bit like a mini A-D...
I search a user using a matching criteria and get a list on a listview
The list view shows 3 fields:
1) User name
2) Display Name
3) eMail address
I want to click on one of the results (the one I need to perform some actions) and see at the same screen if it's locked, disabled and if the user must change password at next logon...
But as I click on the result the program collapse with the above exception.
The above code of in my question shows the functions that should grab the user's object and show the needed info, but it seems wrong